# HTTPRequest.Files.Count Never Equals Zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, httpfilecollection

I have a form on an HTML page that a user needs to use to upload a file which posts to an ASPX page. In the code behind, I want to test if a file has actually been loaded.

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    DoStuff(Request.Files[0]);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("A CSV file must be selected for upload.");
}
```

I am never getting to the else. Is this just how ASP.NET operates? If I have a input element of type file, is it always going to upload a "file" even if one is not selected?

What's the proper way to do this? Maybe this?

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
{
    DoStuff(Request.Files[0]);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("A CSV file must be selected for upload.");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe just this will do:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
{
    DoStuff(Request.Files[0]);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("A CSV file must be selected for upload.");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you access the Files property at all, you can't subsequently call Request.GetBufferlessInputStream: "This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.Form, Files, InputStream, or BinaryRead has been invoked"

Comment: @dudeNumber4 So is selected answer incorrect? I don't have Visual Studio on this computer right now to investigate.

Comment: Well, it's incorrect for me because I need to access that method in order to chunk the (large) uploaded files so they won't overload server memory.  If you don't need to access that method, I suppose you're fine.

Answer (score 7):

`Request.Files.Count` always contains the no. of `<input type="file">` elements in your form, wrapped in a `Key:Value` store.

Hence, if your posted form does not contain any `<input type="file">` tags, then `Request.Files.Count` will return `0`.

Each `Key` is the `name` of the `<input type="file" name="OneOfTheKeys">` and the value is of type  `HttpPostedFileWrapper`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilewrapper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn about `HttpPostedFileWrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the FileUpload control and check .HasFiles to see if anything was uploaded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

Comment: I wish I could use this, but my aspx page is being called from a static html page. :(

Answer (score 1):

Everything was in place as mentioned above. Adding `FormMethod.Post` solved my issue.

```
FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would also make sure that the data being return by the .count method is not a string. A string value of '0' is always greater than a int value of 0; which would always return true in that condition.

I would try typecasting the .count return as an int to make sure that proper types are being compared. Even a string '-1' has a higher bit value than int zero.

just a thought, though I could be wrong....

Comment: `count` would never be a string, since it is of type `int`. Thanks, though.